# MLE of difference is difference of MLEs

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

Suppose a distribution has two parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and let the maximum likelihood estimators for these parameters be $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat \beta$.

Is the maximum likelihood estimator for $\alpha-\beta$ necessarily equal to $\hat{\alpha}-\hat{\beta}?$

We cannot assume the independence of $\hat \alpha$ and $\hat \beta$ since they are both functions of the same data set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the MLE of $\alpha - \beta$ is $\hat{\alpha} - \hat{\beta}$. It is the invariance property of the MLE, namely,  the MLE of $g(\theta)$ is $g(\hat{\theta})$. The only requirement is measurability of the $g$. You can find the proof [here](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Edlunn/b8_02/b8pdf_6.pdf).